# Lock Wordpress /wp-admin/ using password with Apache 2.4

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I want to lock down /wp-admin/ area with a login and password. On Apache 2.3, I used to config my **/var/www/html/wp-admin/.htaccess** like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted files"
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
<Files admin-ajax.php>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</Files>
```

How the same configuration is done on Apache 2.4?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to password restrict wp-admin, which also requires a password, via .htaccess?

Comment: The admin area of WordPress is already restricted, when you go to wp-admin, you'll be prompted to input a username/email and a password.

Comment: Yes, to protect from brute force attacks for example...

Comment: You'd be better off looking for plugins that limit the number of attempts at logins.

Comment: Did you use Google at all? There's several articles - here's one (which has been completely ripped-off in the answer below): http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-password-protect-your-wordpress-admin-wp-admin-directory/

Comment: Yes I did, but I could not find articles with the new Apache 2.4 directives...

Comment: Did you try the same code in .htaccess? If yes, what type of error you are getting?

Comment: Yes, I'm actually using this setting in the ".htaccess" file inside /wp-admin/. The error is that the admin is not asking for a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache 2.4 is exactly the same as 2.2 for password protecting a directory. I use this on a number of sites running on 2.4:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile /this/is/your/dir/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Then you obviously have your .htpasswd file which looks like:

```
admin:Umvdgh40rXES3ChsKg444
```

For access to your file in Apache 2.4:

```
<Files admin-ajax.php>
    Require all granted
</Files>
```

You can view the Apache Documentation for the upgrade by following this link http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what about "admin-ajax.php" file? Access to this file should not be blocked for the proper functioning of Wordpress... The directives "Order allow,deny", "Allow from all" and "Satisfy any" are correct on Apache 2.4?

Comment: Sorry, you didn't specify that in your question, yes there is a slightly change for Apache 2.4. I've made an edit to my question and also included a link to the Apache upgrade documentation.